# For which $n$ there exists such an $m$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question is that:

> For which positive integer $n \geq 2$,there exists an integer $m$ such that $m^2$ is an n-digit number consisting of all the integers from $0$ to $n-1$ when presented in base $n$ system.For example,when $n=4$,$m=15$ meets the requirements because $15^{2}=\left( 3201 \right) _4$ ($a=\left( b \right) _{n}$ denotes that $b$ is the representation of $a$ in base $n$ system).

My attempts:
Let $d_{n}(m)$ be the number of digits of $m$ in base $n$ system.Then we have $n^{2d_{n}(m)-2} \leq m^{2} < n^{2d_{n}(m)}$.Thus $n=d_{n}(m^{2})=2d_{n}(m)$ or $2d_{n}(m)+1$,which means $d_{n}(m)=[\frac{n}{2}]$.

When $n$ is odd,let $n=2^{k+1}\cdot s+1$,$s$ is odd and $k$ is a non-negative integer.Then $m^{2}\equiv \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \equiv 2^{k}\cdot s (mod 2^{k+1}\cdot s)$,thus $2^{k}\parallel m^{2}$,which means $2\parallel k$.So $n=2^{2t+1}\cdot s+1$,where t is a non-negative integer.

When $n$ is even,we have $m^{2}\equiv \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \equiv 0 (mod n-1)$.

This is all the information I can get.How can I solve it?And what condition should $n$ satisfy when it's for $m^{k}$,$k\geq 2$ is an integer?Any help would be appreciated.

And I'm sorry for the possibly wrong expressions for I'm still an English learner.

Comment: This is [A258103](https://oeis.org/A258103) - *Number of pandigital squares (containing each digit exactly once) in base n.*